# Eclipse WindowBuilder not showing the whole JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I installed today the last version of the WindowBuilder add-on on my Eclipse and I keep having this annoying problem where I can't see the whole JFrame in Desing mode. If I try to resize it, it doesn't solve it. It's like if I only had access to see a corner of the JFrame.
I don't seem to have a problem with JPanels so far.
[Please check the picture to see the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZRMF.png)

I tried reinstalling several times both Eclipse and WindowBuilder but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

JPanel sometimes has issues working with other applications. Try uninstalling WindowBuilder and seeing if it works or switch to another IDE

Comment: Yeah, I tried to install and uninstall it several times. I will change to another IDE, yes. but i'm so used to Eclipse at this point that it will require some time of adjustment